# How to load and save partial table in a MySQL-DB with Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, mysql-python

Pandas newbie.

A SQL table is made of 3 columns (ID is the primary key):

```
> ID    VALUE1    VALUE2 
> 1       11        28 
> 2       21      (None) 
> 3       31        56 
> 4       41      (None)
```

With Pandas I load all the rows where VALUE2 is *(None)*:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME`  WHERE (`VALUE2` IS NULL)"
engine = create_engine("mysql://user:pwd@ip/db"
df = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
engine.dispose()
```

Everything ok till now.

Following the load the missing VALUE2 are calculated according to some rules.

**THE PROBLEM**

If I update the database with

```
df.to_sql(TABLE_NAME, con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

All the original lines that were not loaded into the dataframe are LOST:

```
> ID    VALUE1    VALUE2 
> 2       21       103 
> 4       41        72
```

**Is there a way to update leaving the original lines untouched?**

I want to obtain this:

```
> ID    VALUE1    VALUE2 
> 1       11        28 
> 2       21       103 
> 3       31        56 
> 4       41        72
```

It looks like the whole table is rewritten instead of updated...

It would be highly inefficient to load the whole table just to update a few rows. That would virtually solve the problem but it is not acceptable.

Any idea about "why"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a case of mixing the best of two worlds. Do what you are doing at the moment, but use a different table. This is essentially a temporary table but AFAIK pandas doesn't support them so let's just drop it later.

```
df.to_sql(tmp_table_name, con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Then we make use of the [INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (SELECT * FROM tmp_table) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a = VALUES(a), b=VALUES(b) ....
```

This would usually be a fast operation.

Comment: It is a little strange that it is necessary to go through a double step for something so "simple".  Pandas was very close to do the job alone...

Thank you!

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 2):

You're using the option `if_exists="replace"`.

From the Pandas documentation (my emboldening):

> replace: If table exists, **drop it, recreate it**, and insert data.

So it's doing exactly what you're asking of it.  You can try playing around with `if_exists="append"` instead, but it still might not give you the behaviour you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can interact with your table directly using MySQLdb, and use [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html).

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood the "replace": overlooking the docs I thought it is referred to the single record, not to the whole table. Thank you.